# Can I access OpenFeint status/profile page from a browser?

Tags: openfeint

[OpenFeint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFeint) is a platform/system that tracks achievements and scores for mobile games. Many Android and iOS games have OpenFeint support.

However, I don't know how to access OpenFeint status/profile page from outside the game. I want an OpenFeint profile page such as the one from [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/id/CrazyTerabyte/) or [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/CrazyTerabyte). Is there a profile page for OpenFeint? Can I access it from a standard browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since December 14th, OpenFeint has shut down. So this question is not relevant anymore.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFeint
- http://toucharcade.com/2012/11/16/gree-pulls-the-plug-on-openfeint-with-less-than-one-month-notice-to-developers/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that isn't possible. Sorry for that. I think you should search for openfeint in the app store, they have two apps there, but via a browser, not possible